# Is it good idea to create new table for each message beetween 2 user

Tags: sql

Is it good idea to create new table for each message beetween 2 user?For example Jonny and Henry's table for only Jonny and Henry's all messages.Is it fast or column is enough.I want to get best speed.Which one is fast?Create just one messages table for all users or create table for each user(It will be uniqui because its name will be like how their id.For example Jonny id 13 Henry id is 19 and table will be 13_->19)

Comment: Use one table to store messages between all users.  Store only the ids to keep it lean, and add indices.

Comment: Image that I have 1billion user and sql must choose hennry and jonny from one table.It will be very slow?What is wrong with this idea?

Comment: having more tables can cause more slowness. based on your suppose, you might have 1 billion power 2 tables. Does it make sense?

Comment: @IbrahimHasanov: And you think having billions of tables will be better?

Comment: table-per-message would be ludicrously insanely stupid. even a "small" chat system can quickly end up with millions of messages, meaning you'd have millions of tables. assuming you're using mysql, then that's one file per message, and you'd be running out of inodes pretty quickly.

Comment: But I heard that more table is better than more column .I have created one table for whole website with 100 column and they said that it is not correct.And I am decide to do that .And again you say it is slow.If more column is slow how is it possible for more table? @Marc B

Comment: Well, now you are hearing it's not ;)

Comment: What Does it mean which one is better more table or column?

Comment: a message table is extremely simple: `(messageID, sender_id, receiver_id, timestamp, message_content)`. there is absolutely **NO** reason to generate a per-message table.

Comment: Reason is that sql must find 1 records from 2billion messages.But in my way it will find just table

Comment: Finding a record in a table of 2 billion is very fast with the appropriate indexes on the table. A better consideration would be what if you want to show all of one users messages, and they have sent messages to 50 people, you then need to query 50 different tables instead of 1. Which will neither perform well, or be easy to write.

Comment: @IbrahimHasanov: Databases are *very good* at efficiently storing and retrieving data.  Consider for even the briefest of moments that maybe, *just maybe*, people with more experience in this than you have contributed to the design of SQL Server, MySQL, etc.  Now, if you think that perhaps you can write a *better* record storage and retrieval system than a major database vendor, then go for it.  But if that's the case, then what exactly are you asking *us*?  Why do you want *our* validation?

Comment: @David I am just want to understant which one is fast?Columns or tables?Is is fast to search 1 record from 5billion messages(columns) or 1 record from 5 billion tables?

Comment: @IbrahimHasanov: The question you're asking in that comment (performance of columns vs. tables) makes no sense, so there is no reasonable answer.  The answer to the *actual problem* you're facing is that you should design your database in a normalized form.  Creating a separate table for *every record* is absurd.  Now, you're certainly welcome to *do* absurd things if you really want to (and you seem *very keen* on the idea).  But you're not going to find anybody here who *agrees* with the approach.

Comment: @David I want to understant speed.I dont want to prove my idea:).Last time I am just said that I created 1 table with 100 column for one website and everyone disagreed with me.They said more column is slow use just tables.And I think that if there are a little bit more performence on table why is it bad?If table is fast than column it means that 1billion table is fast than 1 billion column.Is not it?

Comment: @IbrahimHasanov: Why would your table have 100 columns?  (And why on Earth would you even *try* to create a table with *1 billion columns*?  Which, by the way, you can't do in any database I've ever seen.)  You seem to be assuming that you can only ever have *one table per database* or *one table per record*.  Both of these ideas are ridiculous.  There is a middle ground where *the entire database design industry* lives.  Create tables which model the *structure* of your data, using foreign keys and other data integrity constraints as needed.  Marc B started you off with a simple table above.

Comment: Yes I understood it.But I didnt say to create 1 table for each record I am just create one table for each conversation(for examle jonny and henry table that contain whole conversation between jonny and henry and I will just write select* from 'jonnyid_->henryid' .I shoul be easy for sql to choose it than select*from messages where sender=jonnyid and receiver =hennryid or sender=henryid and receiver =jonnyid.Is not it?

Comment: @IbrahimHasanov: No, that will not be easier.  The code you write to even *determine* the name of your table is going to be slower than the SQL `WHERE` optimization.  Your system is going to be an order of magnitude slower before the database is even involved.  You've had a bad idea.  Accept that it's a bad idea and move on. If you want to somehow *prove* that it's not a bad idea, then go ahead and implement it and measure the difference.  But no, you have not discovered some amazing new design that's somehow faster than decades of relational database expertise.  Sorry, you're not that clever.

Comment: @David Ok .I am aggree that it is not good idea but it means that more columns is better than more tables.And it is wise verse of my last question on stackover.They said dont write 100 column in one table.Yes I am aggree that idea.But this means that there are some little performance advantage of tables on search for records.Yes and in this case I think that lets use this little advantage and create big advantage and now everyone say me it is also bad idea.Ok I can easily create one message table how marc b said but if  table is more fast than column why shouldnt we use it?

Comment: @IbrahimHasanov: The reason not to do either of these bad ideas isn't because "columns are faster than tables" or "tables are faster than columns".  Neither of those two statements are true because neither of those statements make any sense.  An *efficient* database design is faster than an *inefficient* one.  You've described two horribly inefficient database designs.  Both are slow.  You can spend all the time you want determining *which* of your two bad ideas is the worse of the two.  *Or* you can just abandon them both and design a normal database.

Comment: @IbrahimHasanov You seem to be confusing columns with rows. Your idea of 100 columns was bad, because you would end up storing lots of unrelated things together in a single table. But that does not mean you should have one table per user, it means that you should store users together in one table, messages together in one table, videos together in one table etc. Look at any decent sample database available online and you will get an idea of how a database should be structured.

Comment: @David ok.What about something like ebay .Should I create new table for each category?for example technology,men ,women clothes table etc..

Comment: This question has received good answers. Please accept an answer. That is how SO works.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, modifying the schema (e.g., creating tables) at runtime is a bad, bad idea. Every rule has its exceptions, but unless you have an **extremely** good reason to do this, indexing the relevant columns, or even partitioning your tables by them should be more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

For sure no.
you can keep all of the messages in one table and have some specific columns like sender_id and receiver_id.

Make the relations between tables.

For achieving more speed, consider your indexes, table engine.

And, you can archive your old messages in another table in a specific period

Comment: Why my idea is slow?I search that more table is better than more column also it is easy for search engines and sql to choose messages.And now I am just will say choose jonny and henry table and that's all

Comment: How many records do you have in your table? what are the indexes? did you make the relations? What is your table engine?

Comment: InnobDb .Umage that I have one billion user and there are a lot of table for each conversation and sql must choose jonny and hennry messages ?will not it slow?

Comment: @IbrahimHasanov, having billions of users, needs more consideration. You need to consider the architecture. However, in that case, your idea could down your system

Comment: What about one table for whole website?100 column?

Comment: Why do you need more columns?
we are talking about number of records of one table vs number of tables

Comment: @IbrahimHasanov Take one step at a time. 1) Learn how to design a DB. 2) Learn how to optimize it.